# Visual Studio Code - Highlight selected text on scroll bar disabled with C# extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, scrollbar

Normally in case of Text file VS Code knows highlight selected text appearances on scroll bar, but if I install Microsoft C# extension, this highlight feature stops to work with C# files. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use next line in `settings.json`

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false
```